# In Visa, "+" has been put in place of surname

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, denmark

I applied for a Schengen visa and as I don't have a surname in my passport. I just repeated my given name in the surname field, which is a standard practice.

I have received my visa and they put my name as "+, Given Name". So surname has been replaced with "+".

I have never seen this before. Is this a standard practice? They have asked me to report any errors in names in the visa, so I want to confirm if this is a valid practice.

Comment: It appears that you did not put "+" as your surname in your application, so clearly that is an *error*. They have asked you to report any errors, so what is the issue here?

Comment: @ICanHazUpvotzPleez Don't be so hasty to jump to conclusions: the OP has no surname, so this looks likes an entirely valid way to record that.

Comment: @jpatokal Whether it "looks" like an entirely valid way is irrelevant. The OP mentioned his given name as the surname *in the application*. As far as the consulate is concerned, that *is* his surname. The instructions also clearly ask to report any errors, "+" is not the OP's surname, so that *is* an error. I don't have to "jump" to any conclusions.

Comment: You should add the <country>-schengen-visa and <country>-citizen tags to your post.
I would suggest that you contact the consulate of the country you are visiting, and ask them the clarify if this is how visa are issued to persons with no surname.

Comment: Schengen Embassies has way lot different practices in how they treat/print names & personal details (sequence wise). My name, a two word name written as `First Last` on my passport only in `First` field has been printed in all combinations; sometimes even different by same embassy on different occasions. `F Last` | `Last F` | `Last First` | `First Last` | `First Last +` | `Last First +` I always put First in field first & Last in field last.

Comment: @ICanHazUpvotzPleez "as far as the consulate is concerned, that is his surname": that is incorrect.  The application is not the consulate's only source of information about the applicant's name; there is likely a requirement for the visa to match the passport, which, as we know from the question, *does not show a surname.*

Comment: @phoog Even so, "+" isn't his surname in the passport either, so he should report that to the embassy as instructed. I fail to see why that should need any further explanation.

Comment: I am honestly having difficulty understanding why he should *not* contact the embassy about it. There are two scenarios: 1. Either "+" is the correct way of representing a "missing" surname, in which case, he will get a confirmation from them, and can enjoy his journey and stay in peace. 2. The "+" was a mistake (they have some other convention for missing surnames), in which case, he can figure out how to get it fixed, and then enjoy his journey and stay in peace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using "+" for missing surname is correct practice.
Following is the response from Denmark Embassy:

> Thank you for your email.

> Please be informed that the visa issuance has been done correctly and that you will not face any problems related to the ‘+’ sign on the visa sticker.

> Best Regards